# JavaFX 2.2+. Bad JNLP file. How to fix?

Tags: java, xml, applet, javafx, jnlp

I'm tryin to deploy app on a webserver and havin problems with starting it. It loads GUI properly, but does no reactions on an events. Here is the console log:

```
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: java.lang.AnchorPane: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: java.lang.AnchorPane: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: java.util.AnchorPane: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: java.util.AnchorPane: try again ..
```

and so on. I googled, and founded that the JNLP file was wrong. I checked it with [JaNeLa](http://www.pscode.org/janela/) and founded that it is actually wrong. JaNeLa log:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jfx:javafx-runtime'. One of '{java, j2se, jar, nativelib, extension, property, package}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jfx:javafx-runtime'. One of '{java, j2se, jar, nativelib, extension, property, package}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
```

I googled a lot after it and founded a lot of similar problems, but with no solution. Please help! This is my **[JNLP](http://pastebin.com/wNXA7NU0)** file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="JavaFXApplication1.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>JavaFXApplication1</title>
    <vendor>miceZipper</vendor>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="JavaFXApplication1.jar" size="25531" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="JavaFXApplication1" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="javafxapplication1.JavaFXApplication1"  name="JavaFXApplication1" />
  <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: Note that JaNeLA has not been updated to account for Java FX files.  Looking at it though, it seems to have elements out of order..

Comment: if you're right, then what does that mistake "try again..." mean?

Comment: I had not had time yet to look more closely at the JNLP.  It is important to get that right first.  Do you know of a DTD or XSD for the Java-FX JNLP?

Comment: I have no idea where to find it. I thought that it could be the clue, and if i analize it then i could get the solution, but i found neither Scheme, no way of how my IDE creates it. (i've got NetBeans 7.3.1)